# Python: Add an alphabet to a string

Tags: string, python-3.x, list, alphabetical

Am tryin to add all the alphabet to all the position in a string just one by one, This is the code:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
var = 'abc'
for i in ascii_lowercase:
    result = [var[:j] + i + var[j:] for j in range(len(var))]
```

But this is what am getting :

```
['zabc', 'azbc', 'abzc']
```

This is what am expecting :

```
['aabc', 'abac', 'abca','babc','abbc','abcb'...]
```

Does anyone know how to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: What are you even trying to accomplish with this? The most obvious error is that you're reassigning each time to result. You're also off by one with the `range(len(var))` (should be `range(len(var) + 1)`)

Comment: This isn't code golf... Is there a reason this code can't be more human readable?

Comment: I abdated the post

Comment: You are overwriting `result` on each loop, so you will only see the result of the final character in `ascii_lowercase` being `z`.

Comment: This is just an example, am trying to see if we add an alphabet to string in any position would it be a different word. After finishing the test am going to check the list with a diccionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the whole list at once using a nested list comprehension

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
var = 'abc'

result = [var[:n]+c+var[n:] for c in ascii_lowercase for n in range(len(var)+1)]
```

Comment: This gives duplicates at the start like `"aabc"`.